# Flex Builder 3 debugging trace output

Tags: apache-flex, adobe, flexbuilder

I have installed Flex Builder 3 and Flash Player 10 on my machine.

I don't know where the trace output goes because I just don't see it (I tried debug and output windows).

Also the breakpoints don't hit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Salut Omule :)

If you press the Debug Icon(the bug thingy) or go to Run > Debug you should go to the Debugging perspective.

If might be handy to install the [Flash Tracer plugin for Firefox](http://www.sephiroth.it/firefox/flashtracer/) to see your traces from the browser.

First you need to make sure you have the Debug version of Flash Player 10. You can do that by checking is Debugging is true using [this test](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/155/tn_15507.html).

Comment: There are 3 different Flash debug players, one for IE, one for other browsers and one for standalone purposes (projector.) Make sure you install the Netscape compatible version if you are not using IE.


Also, make sure that Flex Builder is configured properly for Flash 10 debugger, not Flash 9. I am not sure if this issue actually exists in the latest build of Flex Builder, though. It might automatically detect the latest player version.

Comment: Salut George :)
Thanx ppl, everything is working, although i don't know what i did to make it work :)

Answer (score 1):

You can view traced messages in the console (Menubar - Window - Console).

But since you said that breakpoints are not hit, I guess the problem is somewhere else. Make sure that you are debugging instead of running the app (select Debug  from the Run menu or just hit F11 while at the corresponding mxml file).

If that doesn't help, and if you are on Firefox, try uninstalling the last addon that you installed. Some addons (including older versions of google toolbar and adblock plus) have known to block swfs from connecting to the flex builder's debugger.